# S4 doesn't detect any WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I helped my fried to convert from Iphone to S4. I helped him with initial setup and gave some quick crash course. I visited him after a week and answered a few of his questions. I again visited him today after a week. But his Galaxy S4 GT-I9500 has developed a problem.

- The WiFi would stuck on "Turning on" if Bluetooth is switched off.
- The phone won't detect any WiFi. I tried with multiple AP with different settings and even without security.
- It detected the APs for few seconds once during this troubleshooting time of three to four hours.
- Resetting didn't help.

The phone is currently running Android 4.2.2. Any idea on how to make it detect the AP? I'll be trying to flash Android 4.3 via Odin tomorrow. I couldn't do it via Kies as it would say an unknown error occurred.

UPDATE: So I've pushed WiFi Analyzer and playing randomly with WiFi Settings and WiFi analyzer brings WiFi back for good. But same problem after factory reset. And again repeating above actions fixes it.

Comment: I should say it works because it can detect other Bluetooth devices.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there any reason that you're focusing on Bluetooth here?

Comment: So I've pushed WiFi Analyzer and playing randomly with WiFi Settings and WiFi analyzer brings WiFi back for good. But same problem after factory reset. And again repeating above actions fixes it.

Comment: Alright, I guess that axes my hypothesis.  I went ahead and added that info to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was hardware related. WiFi chip was changed in the service center. Now it is working OK.

Answer (score 0):

Is it using a custom ROM or a modified stock ROM?

Flashing DjeMBeY's [pre-rooted S4 ROMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2250824) has issues with Wi-Fi, esp. for those higher than `MGA`. They have a Wi-Fi fix, but I still encountered issues (e.g. intermittent mobile data, loss of audio / sound). So, I downgraded back to MGA.

Hopefully reading the thread in XDA might give you some ideas. Do share your answer if you find something useful, or a solution.

Comment: It is running stock ROM. Updated to 4.3 via ODIN still same issue. Tried two 4.3 ROMs, one for UAE where the device was originally purchased and one for Nepal where it is being used.

Comment: @roxan Have you done factory reset, clear cache, clear dalvik cache? Then, flashing stock 4.3 ROM?

Comment: Yes. Tried resetting from Settings menu. Tries clearing cache and installing ROM from ODIN. BTW there is no option to clear dalvik cache on stock ROM.

Comment: @roxan What if you flash a new stock 4.2 ROM? observe it first. then if it's ok, then maybe you can do an OTA update?

Comment: Well 4.2 stock ROM already had the problem. I don't want to download another 1.5GB until I can see some logic behind this step. Internet is very expensive and slow here :)

Comment: @roxan What is the version? XXUBMGA?

Comment: I've tried I9500XXUEMJ5_I9500OJVEMJ5_XSG.zip I9500XXUEMJ9_I9500ODDEMJ5_NPL.zip and I9500XXUEMJ8_I9500ODDEMJ5_NPL.zip

Comment: @roxan I wasn't successful with MJ5 (4.3). How about you try MGA (4.2) first?

Comment: What do you mean by you weren't successful? Do you also have a similar problem? OK I'll once try with 4.2 next time I go there solely based on your reputation here :) . BTW what is MJ5 and MGA?

Comment: @roxan MGA refers to the last 3 letters of the ROM (e.g. MJ5 in I9500XXUEMJ5 of I9500XXUEMJ5_I9500OJVEMJ5_XSG.zip)  I used djembey's prerooted ROM (MJ5 version), but I had issues with mobile data. It kept turning off every once in a while, even when I flashed the correct modem.

Comment: @roxan I hope other folks can try and help, but it seems you're getting input from me only though. I went back to MGA (lower 4.2 version) because I couldn't get 4.3 to work properly on my phone).

Comment: I went there again. WiFi stopped working after working for few days. I think it is hardware problem.

Comment: @roxan Have it checked if it's still under warranty. :)

Comment: Despite being only few weeks old, the warranty can't be claimed. It was bought from a different country.(UAE->Nepal). Will still try to see if someone can take it back their to claim warranty.